# Title is showing in page when its inside <head>

Tags: html, head, document-body, page-title

I made a short and basic website and the title is showing in the page. I put the title inside head when i wrote it but it is inside body when i use the inspect tool on it. [Screenshot of code editor and inspect tool on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7bvt.png)

**Code is below:**

````
    <head>
       <tittle>Race registration form</tittle>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Race registration!</h1>
        <form action="/Registration_form">
            <p>
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
            </p>
            <p>
                Select a race:
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" id="Fun Run 5K" name="Race" value="Fun Run 5K">
                <label for="Fun Run 5K">Fun Run 5K</label>
            </p>  
            <p>   
                <input type="radio" id="Half Marathon" name="Race" value="Half Marathon">
                <label for="Half Marathon">Half Marathon</label> 
            </p>
            <p> 
                <input type="radio" id="Full Marathon" name="Race" value="Full Marathon">
                <label for="Full Marathon">Full Marathon</label>
            </p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input tupe="password" id="password" name="password"> <br>
            <p>
            <button type="submit">Register!</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `tittle` has an extra `t` there, and needs to be `title`.

Because `<tittle />` is not a valid tag that belongs to `head` area, it's bleeding into `body`. Fix the typo, and it'd go away.